# Get file content from file input field

Tags: javascript, file-upload, input-field

So, I have an input field, I have the file list object containing the files, but I can't see how to get at the file content. What I want to do is use crypto-js to generate an md5 hash of the file. 
I want to use the hash as a reference to the file (i.e. asrjq38w94r5yh8hrqw9.jpg) and also so I can veryfy file integrity to insure the file got uploaded correctly.

Is the only way to do this by getting the file path from the file input field and then using the `FileReader` object to get the file content?

Comment: FileReader is pretty much it.

Comment: awwww, it makes sense to me that file input should have access, the fact that you have to use something else is a bit.. silly to me.